In Blazor checkbox won't stay checked
I have a simple todolist app in Blazor where when I check a todo item the list of todos are written to a json file. It works up until the last checkbox. The last checkbox won't write to the json file and won't stay checked.
I tried to write to a text file as well as called async methods and StateHasChanged, but nothing seems to work.
@page "/todo"
@rendermode InteractiveServer
@inject API.IApi todoApi

<PageTitle>Todo</PageTitle>

<h3>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h3>

<input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="ValidFormSubmitted" class="btn btn-primary">Add Todo</button>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input @key="todo" type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" @oninput="CheckboxChanged"/>
            <input class="border-0" type="text" @bind="todo.Title" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@code {
    public List<TodoItem> todos = new();
    public string? newTodo = "";

    public async Task ValidFormSubmitted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");

        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            await Task.Run(() => todoApi.Write(todos));
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        todos = await Task.FromResult(todoApi.Read());
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized");
    }

    public async Task CheckboxChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => todoApi.Write(todos));
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

}

Here is the code for writing to a json file:
using System.Text.Json;

namespace Todolist.API
{
    public class JsonApi: IApi
    {

        public void Write(List<TodoItem> todos)
        {
            string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(todos);
            File.WriteAllText("todos.json", json);
        }

        public List<TodoItem> Read()
        {
            string filename = "todos.json";
            string json = "";
            List<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();

            if (File.Exists(filename) && File.ReadLines(filename).Any())
            {
                json = File.ReadAllText(filename);
                todos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TodoItem>>(json);
                return todos;
            }
            else
            {
                File.Create(filename).Close();
                return todos;
            }
        }
    }
}

Screenshot of last checkbox not checking

You're trying to make your I/O async by offloading it to another thread.  You're read code and OnInitializedAsync executes synchronously.  And you don't need to pass the write off to the threadpool.  Use the async versions of read and write.
Instead of trying to explain why, I'll point you to this article which explains about async I/O operations and the There is no Thread truth - https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html.
Here's a refactored version of you code:

public class TodoItem
{
    public string? Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
}

public class JsonApi
{
    public async ValueTask WriteAsync(List<TodoItem> todos)
    {
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(todos);
        await File.WriteAllTextAsync("todos.json", json);
    }

    public async ValueTask<List<TodoItem>> ReadAsync()
    {
        string filename = "todos.json";
        string json = "";
        List<TodoItem> todos = new List<TodoItem>();

        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filename);
            try
            {
                todos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TodoItem>>(json);
            }
            catch (JsonException)
            {
                // Return an empty list
            }

            return todos ?? new List<TodoItem>();
        }
        else
        {
            File.Create(filename).Close();
            return new List<TodoItem>();
        }
    }
}

In your component code you're using @oninput when you should be using @bind:after. This guarantees that the value will be updated before you attempt to save the model.
@page "/"
@inject JsonApi todoApi

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<PageTitle>Todo</PageTitle>

<h3>Todo (@todos.Count(todo => !todo.IsDone))</h3>

<input placeholder="Something todo" @bind="newTodo" />
<button @onclick="ValidFormSubmitted" class="btn btn-primary">Add Todo</button>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
    @foreach (var todo in todos)
    {
        <li>
            <input @key="todo" type="checkbox" @bind="todo.IsDone" @bind:after="CheckboxChanged" />
            <input class="border-0" type="text" @bind="todo.Title" />
        </li>
    }
</ul>

<div class="bg-dark text-white m-2 p-2">
    @foreach(var item in todos)
    {
        <pre>@item.Title - @item.IsDone</pre>
    }
</div>

@code {
    public List<TodoItem> todos = new();
    public string? newTodo = "";

    public async Task ValidFormSubmitted()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Clicked");

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newTodo))
        {
            todos.Add(new TodoItem { Title = newTodo });
            await todoApi.WriteAsync(todos);
            newTodo = string.Empty;
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        todos = await todoApi.ReadAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Initialized");
    }

    public async Task CheckboxChanged()
    {
        await todoApi.WriteAsync(todos);
    }
}

